# Как не выпускать фокус за пределы модального окна?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend, ui

Пишу на  vue.js компонент мадального окна. И хочется, что бы при открытом модальном окне, при нажатии клавиши tab, полбзователь попадал бы на первый активный элемнт в окне, а не на странице сайта. Так же, хочется, что бы при последуючих табах, при открытом окне, фокус получали бы только элементы этого окна. Содержимое окна будет передаваться через slot. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли это как то сделат?